favicon issue 500 for node js locally work but in vercel give error
First, I have added public folder out side of src inside, I have favicon.ico.
Then in my code, I have implemented this thing:
'use strict';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import path from 'path';

import { PORT } from './config/server.config.js';

import apiRouter from './routes/index.js';
import errorHandler from './utils/errorHandler.js';
import connectToDB from './config/db.config.js';
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';
import upload from './utils/fileUpload.js';
import 'express-async-errors';

const app = express();
import cors from 'cors';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

// Define __dirname manually
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

//middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.text());
// app.use(fileUpload());
const corsOptions = {
  origin: ['https://react-admin-ten-omega.vercel.app'],
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
console.log('Serving static files from:', path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// app.use(upload.single('companyLogo'));

app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Favicon requested');

  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public/favicon.ico'));
});

//test vercel

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Welcome to Admin Task');
});

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

app.use(errorHandler);

const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    await connectToDB();
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server Started at PORT: ${PORT}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error starting server:', error);
    throw new Error('Database connection failed');
  }
};

startServer();

this code is working locally in port 3000 but for vercel issue is https://admin-task-five.vercel.app/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
I have tried getting a function that helps to avoid the favicon issue many times, but the issue can't be solved by me.
I have tried with get midddleware for solving this favicon issue but was unable to solve it.

FYI you don't need to use 'use strict' if you use ESM

I am not sure if this will work in your case.
But if i were you i would try the following steps.

Checking for static asset paths. Why you ask? Its because the path for your favicon.ico may differ on vercel. So i will double check it.

something like this ->
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico'));


Vercel Deployment Configuration. Because vercel use this config file to know what to do when some requests come.

It goes like this (vercel.json) ->
{
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/favicon.ico", "destination": "/public/favicon.ico" }
  ]
}

Next for extra debugging i would put debugging logs everywhere and will also check Vercel logs to find out the issue.
